# Which approach is better for checking if the number is a whole number?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to check if the number is a whole number or a square number. I know two possible ways. Just want to know which approach is better.

---

1. `if (Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number)) ==  Math.sqrt(number) )`
2. `if (Math.sqrt(number) % 1 == 0)`

Comment: Are you trying to test if the square root is an integer?

Comment: yes! i know how to do that just not sure which approach is the best

Comment: I wouldn't do either of those two.  I'd cast the result of `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))` to a long, and then I'd test whether the square of that number was equal to the original number (also cast to long).

Comment: What's the upper bound on the argument?  Or is it `Double.MAX_VALUE`?  The correct approach may vary depending on how big the number can be, due to floating-point precision issues.

Comment: haven't really thought about that

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
double result = Math.sqrt(number);
if (result == (int)result){
    // is integer
}
```

Quick and simple.

Comment: Not sure if will always work, as comparing floats is never guaranteed, due to floating point imprecision.